# (C# UWP) Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core, Database CRUD ops

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-desktop

I'm starting to work with Sqlite for a database so that I can include in one of my other projects sometime later. I created a C# UWP application following this example from Microsoft using **Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core** instead of *Microsoft.Data.Sqlite*.

Link to example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

So, now I'm trying to add all CRUD implementations, although a couple ones are already done in that example. Well, I've looked at other examples of Sqlite online and it seems different than what mine is? I.e., I saw an example where they used **__dbConnection.Prepare(cmdString)** and my SqliteConnection obj does not have a *Prepare()* function. Also, for ex., I saw another where the SqliteConnection has an *Update()* function too, and I do not have that.

I was just testing with trying to add in an *Update()* function and here is what I put, which may not be the correct way to update items in a database using this version of Sqlite?

```
    public static void UpdateItem()
    {
        using (SqliteConnection db =
            new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
        {
            // Currently makes all of them change (FIX)
            db.Open();
            SqliteCommand updateCommand = new SqliteCommand
                ("UPDATE MyTable SET [Text_Entry]=@text", db);
            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "TESTING UPDATE CMD");
            updateCommand.ExecuteReader();
            db.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was just testing with trying to add in an Update() function and here is what I put, which may not be the correct way to update items in a database using this version of Sqlite?

No. You're also on the correct way. The examples you've seen are probably older versions of SQLite usage in UWP. The document you mentioned also has been updated many times. You just need to follow the latest document to use the SQLite in your UWP app.